# rust-analyzer failed to load workspace: Failed to read Cargo metadata from Cargo.toml file e:\rustBlog\server\Cargo.toml

Tags: rust

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2KEv.png)
**I create rust project by "cargo new [name]" and install rust-analyzer in vsCode.But when I open the project by vscode,there's an error "rust-analyzer failed to load workspace: Failed to read Cargo metadata from Cargo.toml file e:\rustBlog\server\Cargo.toml, cargo 1.60.0 (d1fd9fe2c 2022-03-01): Failed to parse edition 2021: invalid edition: "2021"".How to resolve it? **

cargo --version 1.60.0
rustc --version 1.60.0
rust-analyzer version 0.2.297

Comment: What does `cargo -V` prints?

Comment: If RA doesn't understand edition 2021 then it sounds like it or your Rust installation is very out of date. Try updating Rust and rust-analyzer and restarting VsCode and see if you get the same issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: cargo --version 1.60.0 ,
rustc --version 1.60.0,
rust-analyzer version 0.2.297,

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by update vsCode to newest version "1.67.1" and uninstall vscode extension named "Rust".The two of them are in conflict!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this method works for me, and just wanna share what I found to resolve this issue.

[image: Rust Analyzer Error]

So I have multiple projects open in VSCode, which few of them is "non Rust" Project. You can imagine the structure like this

```
-
 |- my-golang-project
 |- my-vite-project
 |- my-rust-project
```

Then reorder the 1st and 2nd project to the last one, or close them from the workspace then reopen again (so the project will be placed after) like this

```
-
 |- my-rust-project
 |- my-golang-project
 |- my-vite-project
```

This makes the rust-analyzer re-scanning the project and everything seems to be working for me

[image: no red crossmark]